# Arduino read JSON data

Tags: arduino

Can you help me to solve a problem? I'm using an Arduino. How can I read and split JSON data in Arduino? The value is `{$sen1:$sen2}`.

Comment: Format Code Properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Example**

How to **deserialize** a JSON document with **ArduinoJson**.

Source code

```
// ArduinoJson - arduinojson.org
// Copyright Benoit Blanchon 2014-2017
// MIT License

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial port
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) continue;

  // Memory pool for JSON object tree.
  //
  // Inside the brackets, 200 is the size of the pool in bytes.
  // Don't forget to change this value to match your JSON document.
  // Use arduinojson.org/assistant to compute the capacity.
  StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;

  // StaticJsonBuffer allocates memory on the stack, it can be
  // replaced by DynamicJsonBuffer which allocates in the heap.
  //
  // DynamicJsonBuffer  jsonBuffer(200);

  // JSON input string.
  //
  // It's better to use a char[] as shown here.
  // If you use a const char* or a String, ArduinoJson will
  // have to make a copy of the input in the JsonBuffer.
  char json[] =
      "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";

  // Root of the object tree.
  //
  // It's a reference to the JsonObject, the actual bytes are inside the
  // JsonBuffer with all the other nodes of the object tree.
  // Memory is freed when jsonBuffer goes out of scope.
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

  // Test if parsing succeeds.
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
    return;
  }

  // Fetch values.
  //
  // Most of the time, you can rely on the implicit casts.
  // In other case, you can do root["time"].as<long>();
  const char* sensor = root["sensor"];
  long time = root["time"];
  double latitude = root["data"][0];
  double longitude = root["data"][1];

  // Print values.
  Serial.println(sensor);
  Serial.println(time);
  Serial.println(latitude, 6);
  Serial.println(longitude, 6);
}

void loop() {
  // not used in this example
}
```